# How to keep printing from a location even after encountering null in C?

Tags: c, linux

`printf("The read text is \n %s\n", local[0].iov_base);`
I am trying to print from a specific memory range , My string is stored there. I am able to print if I give exact address of the start, but when I try to put address little before the exact, null is encountered and nothing is printed as shown below:

```
➜  Test sudo ./Snoop 39075 0x5567fd9922a0 135168
 * Launching with a target PID of: 39075
 * Launching with a target address of 0x5567fd9922a0
 * Launching with a buffer size of 135168 bytes.
 * Executed process_vm_ready, read 134496 bytes.
The read text is My Sample Text
➜  Test sudo ./Snoop 39075 0x5567fd992200 1351689
 * Launching with a target PID of: 39075
 * Launching with a target address of 0x5567fd992200
 * Launching with a buffer size of 1351689 bytes.
 * Executed process_vm_ready, read 134656 bytes.
The read text is
```

I need to print more, or send everything from local[0].iov_base to a char string so I may print as

```
for(i=0;i<bufferLength;i++)
    {
      printf("%c",mystuff[i]);
    }
```

Whole code I am using: https://gist.github.com/FergusInLondon/fec6aebabc3c9e61e284983618f40730

Comment: `printf("The read text is \n %s\n", local[0].iov_base,local[0].iov_base);` your compiler did not warn you?

Comment: Also, you cannot achieve what you want with _string_ operation. You have to do individual character processing (one at a time).

Comment: You cannot use "string" functions to print bytes with value zero... try `write(1, address, nbytes);` on a POSIX system

Comment: Only print printable characters. Printing arbitrary bytes may have unpredictable effect on your terminal.

Comment: @SouravGhosh How do I read individual characters one by one from memory ? My main task is to print whatever is in the stack of another process without halting the task (Ptrace halts the task) so I am trying to do the same by using process_vm_readv(). I also tried `read(fp,buffer,sizetoread);` fp opened /proc/{pid}/mem.
& I fixed that compiler error.. I was testing something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is an array of characters which end with `\0`. So `printf()` will not work. To output an array of characters you can use `fwrite()`.
`fwrite()` has this declaration:

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

`ptr` points to the data you want to output, `size`*`count` is the size of the object you want to output, the return value is the number elements written, normally same as `count`. If it is different from `count`, you can check for errors with `feof()`.

You can use `stdout` for `stream` when you want to print to stdout. But keep in mind that printing binary data to the terminal is not a good idea because it can mess up the terminal. A better idea is to write to a real file or encode it in something like hexadecimal, but then you have to write your own encoding function.

I do not think it is a good idea to run your programs with root privileges, which i assume you do because you use sudo, when you do not understand the basics of c programming. It is better when you learn a bit more before you give your programs the permissions to break you OS.

Comment: I think I will follow your advice, make my own encoding function. I have to run program as sudo as I am accessing memory of other process, I am doing it on a VM (Virtual Machine) because of the risk only. Thanks